# I am looking to get second element from array which stored in dataframe column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have dataframe df1 and column name is data which having rows like below and want to get secon element of array.

```
[1,5,2,5,8,3,4]
[3,4]
[5]
[]
[8, 5,0,2,5,8,1,4]
```

And I want ouput like

```
5,5,3
4
null
null
5,2,1
```

Comment: Can you explain why the last row return 5,2,1 instead of 5,2,8,4?

Answer (score 0):

Pls check below code -

```
df = df.withColumn("output", F.expr("transform(value, (x, i) -> CASE WHEN i % 2 != 0 THEN x ELSE NULL END)"))
df = df.withColumn('result', F.expr('filter(output, x -> x is not null)')).withColumn("result", F.concat_ws(", ",F.col("result")))
```